# Read and Write to specific line in textfile with VB.Net 2

Tags: vb.net, file, overwrite

I have tried using the solution (given below) for the "Read and Write to specific line in textfile with VB.Net" problem asked 4 years ago

```
Dim filePath As String = "E:\myFile.txt"
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
If lines.Length > 4 AndAlso lines(4).StartsWith("ORIGIN ") Then
    lines(4) = "ORIGIN ""250"""
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines)
End If
```

But each time I encounter the following error:

> The process cannot access the file 'file_path' because it is being
>   used by another process.

Any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: You have it open by another app? :)

Comment: "System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines)" this is the line that gives the error. Thank you in advance :))

Comment: I don't. However I am reading the same file with a StreamReader object to store the number of line on which that string was found. For e.g. if ORIGIN "250" is found on the second line then I store 2 in an Integer variable ;say i. This I use in the following way- lines(i-1) = "ORIGIN ""250""". I even used StreamReader object's .dispose and .close before using the above code but that didn't help.

Comment: you could use Process Explorer or some tool like that to find if the file is open by some process.

Comment: Declare the `StreamReader` with a [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). See the example there.

Comment: I used process explorer, its seems like 2 processes are trying to use the same file. I have closed the object using the file in the code before trying to write into the file. I don't know where I'm going wrong. Will try to work my way around this. Thanks for the quick replies. Also I tried the 'using' declaration, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Issue has been resolved... thank you all so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works OK for me. `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` is supposed to close the file afterwards.

Maybe something else is preventing write access to the file. (Some application you're using to see if it's working?!) To check that, replace

```
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
```

with

```
Dim lines() As String = {"0","1","2","3","ORIGIN 4", "5"}
```

and see if it still fails.